# how print variable values in Go with fmt.Printl?

Tags: go, gofmt

I have the below code snippet:

```
x_variable := 12311
fmt.Println("message", "X variable has the value '+x_variable+' printed in the screen now")
```

How can I make that work?
I've tried that in the Go playground but couldn't figure it out how to print the vaue properly.

Comment: What's wrong with `fmt.Println("abc", x, "xyz")`? It gives `abc 1234 xyz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x_variable := 12311
    fmt.Printf("message X variable has the value %d printed in the screen now", x_variable)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you need is [Sprintf](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf)

You can find already an [example](https://go.dev/play/p/geqloT6q3_H) there.

Since you want to print an integer, you can use the `%d` modifier.

Keep in mind that `Sprintf` family does not insert newline automatically, so you will also need `\n`

Comment: `Sprintf` doesn't print a value, it returns a value.